# Facebook iOS invite

Tags: ios, facebook, invite, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I have an app that allows users to invite their friends to download the app. This all works fine, the friend gets the notification via the FB app and bobs your uncle. The issue is that when you click 'install now' Facebook doesn't load the app in the App Store, it's just blank. I have an appID which has an old version of the app without any FB integration in it.

Any ideas why the facebook app isn't loading the App Store? [image: this is what it looks like when you click install now]

Comment: Just to make sure: you filled your app id at http://developers.facebook.com -> Apps > Settings > iPhone Store ID / iPad Store ID, right?

Comment: Yup. Did that. But doesn't seem to want to load it @EduardoViegas

Comment: Would you have the App ID for me, please? Also, a link to the iTunes store?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, I found the issue. I was using the wrong app link URL.